# H14 error in heroku - "no web processes running"

Tags: python, html, django, heroku, web-deployment

error H14 happen while deploying to heroku
this is my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -k gevent main:app
```

log on heroku:

```
2017-01-23T10:42:58.904480+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=meetcapstone.herokuapp.com request_id=df88efb5-a81a-4ac0-86dc-4e03d71266bb fwd="81.218.117.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-23T10:42:59.009135+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=meetcapstone.herokuapp.com request_id=21cea981-36b0-4410-891f-548bbc29f0ee fwd="81.218.117.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

requirements:

```
Flask==0.11.1
passlib==1.7.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.5
Werkzeug==0.11.15
gunicorn==19.0.0
gevent==1.2.1
```

Comment: Please show the whole log from the time you deployed. Were there any errors starting gunicorn?

Answer (score 221):

The issue here is that you're not running any web dynos. You can tell Heroku to do this via:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

This will force Heroku to spin up a web dyno, thereby executing your gunicorn command.

Comment: should i write it in the procfile?

Comment: amazing! i got this issue to trigger after putting in a malformed procfile and then correcting it

Comment: Weird, the dyno in the Heroku dashboard had to be disabled first. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! For some reason the embedded tomcat tutorial did not require me to do this, yet the webapprunner tutorial did. No clue why the difference.

Comment: Man! One day trying to fix this, I am deploying a container to Heroku and I changed the `web` in `build` to my app's name, I didn't think that mattered... Heroku should be more clear on their tutorials.

Comment: @jpenna please how did u deploy your containers to heroku. Been trying to do that for weeks.

Comment: @medobills I ran `heroku stack:set container` and then I created the `heroku.yml` file with `build: docker: web: Dockerfile`, and deployed it to Heroku using the `git push heroku master`. The problem was that I changed the `web: Dockerfile` to `myApp: Dockerfile`... Check this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml, I think it should work fine if you follow these steps and you have your Dockerfile correct and your containers are running fine locally. Tell if it works.

Comment: wow thanks! i had this problem after downgrading the dyno and this one liner works!

Comment: Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).

Comment: (ah ok, was missing a Procfile --very confusing unless you use their example code)

Comment: If you have already deployed without and dynos and are getting the error "Couldn't find that process type (web).", then you need to remove your buildpacks first, then set ps:scale, and then put the buildpacks back.  See: https://help.heroku.com/W23OAFGK/why-am-i-seeing-couldn-t-find-that-process-type-when-trying-to-scale-dynos

Comment: I had the "Couldn't find that process type (web)" issue. The fix was to create a Procfile. I'm deploying a Django app so the file contained "web: gunicorn <myappname>.wsgi". Full docs are here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: !    Couldn't find that process type (web).

Comment: Doesn't work any more if you come from a free plan. You are forced to eco now.

Answer (score 48):

After 3 hours of debugging, I've figured out why *my app* was causing this error:

1. My `Procfile` was incorrectly cased
2. `gunicorn` wasn't installed in my `venv`

*IMO, this error should be raised on Heroku's end. As a beginner, this sort of error is difficult to trace.*

**Update:**
To clarify, `Procfile` is correctly cased and `procfile` is not correctly cased. It should start with a capital `"P"`.

> More info on [dyno configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-configurations) – more on initializing your [heroku app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

Comment: To clarify, `Procfile` is correctly cased and `procfile` is **not** correctly cased. It should start with a capital P.

Answer (score 21):

I ran into the same problem but from a different cause. I had the hobby tier, but then canceled it and reverted back to the free tier. Doing this caused the error and how I fixed it was just re running the command from the cli:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: Getting an error when running this command ..`Scaling dynos... !  Couldn't find that process type (web).`

Comment: heroku ps:scale web=1 --app APP_NAME_IN_HEROKU worked for me!

Answer (score 15):

Before this command:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

I had to remove and add buildpacks again and empty commit it and redeploy it to heroku.

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:add --index heroku/python
```

Comment: I got `Error: Expected an integer but received: heroku/python` with your last command

Comment: heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python

Comment: !    Couldn't find that process type (web).

Answer (score 11):

My issue is that Heroku removed the free plans. To solve such an issue go to Heroku and select/change your free plan to for example "eco" plan.

Comment: This was my issue, as well. For anyone who is looking for an alternative with a free plan, I recommend researching "PaaS hosting providers with a free tier."

Answer (score 7):

I was having an issue here too. My problem was that my Procfile was "Procfile.txt"  .
What solved my issue was to remove the file extension from Procfile, then recommit 
and push stuff to heroku

Answer (score 7):

- Login to your Heroku dashboard and open your projects.
- Go to Settings.
- Delete `heroku/python` from the list of buildpacks
- Then click Add buildpack → Choose "Python" → Save Changes.
- Activate your environment in your code.
- Run `heroku ps:scale web=1`.

And you're done!

Comment: what do you mean by activate your environment in your code?

Answer (score 7):

This isn't the problem with your code, but I've gotten this error message a couple of times now and the mistake that I've made that has caused it has been writing

```
web:gunicorn
```

instead of

```
web: gunicorn
```

That space can really cause a lot of issues.

Answer (score 7):

I have a UAT version I only enable during client development.

I have a custom dyno script but it's turned to the free version. So the app was not starting as my script was not running. When I enabled the Dyno the toggle was still off :rolleyes:

[image]

Comment: after few hours of debugging I have found out that this slider was disable in my heroku app

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to reply to the correct comment, but for me the issue was that I didn't have the **run.gunicorn.sh** file in my root directory, this resulted in the same "No web processes running" error.

If you don't have this file, create it with contents:

```
gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - build:app
```

Where 'build' is the name of your python file (build.py in this case) and app is the name of your app in the code.

Also make sure that gunicorn is included in requirements.txt, like others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I was also using `web heroku-php-apache2` dyno and reverted it back to free tier and that caused the dyno to sleep fortunately executing `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a <app name>` did the magic.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Procfile file from
web:gunicorn to web gunicorn (remove the ':')

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by going to Configure Dynos and enabling the only dyno I had manually.

Answer (score 1):

uff..that took some time,so the fixes i had to make were:

1. 'Procfile' with upper case P.
2. `web: gunicorn wsgi:app`  (with a space after `web:` in procfile)
3. Making sure the requirements.txt are in the root project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes running `heroku ps:scale web=1` does not fix the issue, a workaround i found useful is scaling up the dynos then scaling them down to your initial price i.e bumping it to 25$ then scaling it back to 7$

Answer (score 1):

Try scale down the dyno first.

```
heroku ps:scale web=0
```

Then scale it up.

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing dynos on the web gui. The cli command to scale did not work. I also may have had an incorrect run:web declaration with missing $PORT. To fix:

heroku.yml must have a web declaration using the $PORT var:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
```

I then pushed to heroku.

After that it must have added the web dyno, I could then run:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

And now the fastapi uvicorn runs.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the Procfile naming and location (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) The Procfile is always a "simple text file" that is named Procfile without a file extension.(Procfile.txt not acceptable!) The Procfile must live in your app's root directory. It does not function if placed anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the exact same problem turns out I had the `Profile` in `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

I was placing my django Procfile in the directory with settings.py and not the root directory and that gave me the H14 error. I fixed the error with this and I didn't need to do anything else they say.

```
Procfile
```

---

web: gunicorn <django-root-name(containing wsgi)>.wsgi

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can go wrong here. Its a combination of poor shepherding by heroku and ambiguous use between flask & gunicorn.

Here is a [good guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-python-flask-app-on-heroku/#:%7E:text=Deploying%20Flask%20App%20on%20Heroku&text=STEP%201%20%3A%20Create%20a%20virtual,and%20install%20Flask%20and%20Gunicorn%20.&text=STEP%202%20%3A%20Create%20a%20%E2%80%9CProcfile,and%20write%20the%20following%20code.&text=STEP%203%20%3A%20Create%20%E2%80%9Cruntime.) that will get you up and running:

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may come across this...

1. delete your Procfile
2. create 'Procfile' with upper case P.
3. in your Procfile type: `web: gunicorn <nameOfRootFile>:app` (with a space after web: in procfile) mine for example was `web: gunicorn app:app` another way I wrote it that worked was this: `web: gunicorn -w 4 "app:create_app()" -t 120`
4. Making sure the requirements.txt are in the root project folder. (you can run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` if you do not have the file created
5. deploy to heroku
6. `heroku ps:scale web=1` (you can specify app name to like this `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a appname`
7. finally in terminal run heroku restart
8. heroku open

these are all the steps i took to get mine to work

Answer (score 0):

```
web: gunicorn weather.wsgi --log-file -
```

this worked for me, just make sure your **Procfile** is in the right format, and specify the app you are connecting to, in my case it's the **weather** app. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue because my application was deployed on the free plan before and its size was more than 300MB. The application worked fine again when I did the following:

1. Upgrade account to eco plan
2. Deleted the application
3. Create new application on heroku for the same project and deployed
   it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was adding on the second line of the `procfile`:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

The first line must contain:

```
web: gunicorn "filename":"main method name"
```