# How should is a procfile made?

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, procfile

I have made a project named mysite with django i cloned it to a directory named tes the directory is as followed. As you can see the procfile is in correct directory.

```
test
├── blog
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── procfile
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
```

The Procfile is as follows:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

I have also tried

```
web: gunicorn test.wsgi --log-file -
```

but still i get the error no web process runnig.

the heroku log file is..

```
2017-06-04T08:47:14.090800+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=book19.herokuapp.com request_id=036b18d7-2833-4472-be5d-421c13014a94 fwd="47.247.3.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: i would remove the other `procfile`. The line with `mysite.wsgi` is the correct one. This is may not be a Procfile issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running

Comment: actually the spelling of the other procfile is incorrect so i dont think it would cause any problem.

Comment: it can cause issues in git. if you simply rename a file from `procfile` -> `Procfile`, it won't get picked up, and you won't send a valid `Procfile` to heroku. That said, i agree, it is incorrect, but probably not the problem here. See the link i posted, or search "error no web process running". Many people have posted various solutions to this same problem.

Comment: I tried but every solution and even the heroku app dashboard says add a process in your procfile.

Comment: heliotrope right! Remove the procifle with small. And try the mysite.wsgi

Comment: Can you show us your heroku log when you git push?

Comment: I did remove the procfile

Comment: you can see if your Procfile works locally just by running `heroku local`

Comment: Thank you for all your help it was my dumb mistake i was editing the procfile with the wrong name where as the correct Procfile was empty sorry for wasting you time