# Heroku Application Error failing to deploy

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask, cmd

I am trying to deploy my site on Heroku.

I've used the following command "heroku logs --tail" in my cmd and it returns with the following code:

```
2019-07-31T23:55:23.815010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kobadatech.herokuapp.com request_id=2a5d4d0d-3ebb-47eb-8361-d8b870dd64be fwd="46.69.72.14" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 !    Logs eventsource failed with: 401 Unauthorized
```

This is the link to my Heroku page: https://kobadatech.herokuapp.com/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [H14 error in heroku - "no web processes running"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running)

Comment: Are your `buildpack`, `procfile` and `requirements.txt` correct?