# Django website deployed on heroku does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, gunicorn

I created a django website and was trying to deploy it to heroku. I followed this  tutorial and did everything he did but i'm getting these errors in the logs

```
2020-07-10T02:06:01.015381+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=website.herokuapp.com request_id=9efff235-77f8-41e8-bc9e-9f80bd2b6aa1 fwd="172.98.86.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-07-10T02:06:01.743381+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=website.herokuapp.com request_id=bf2f44a0-8f5c-4e63-a1c9-e16a33761803 fwd="172.98.86.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

my procfile has these contents

```
web: gunicorn website.wsgi --log-file -
```

my requirements.txt includes these

```
asgiref==3.2.3
Django==2.1.7
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.9
psycopg2==2.8.4
Jinja2==2.10.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

I used to get the same HTTP errors when running the site locally but the site used to render and work properly. I'm getting the same error in  heroku but site is not working

Can someone explain what these error means and how to fix them or you could also reply with a link to a video or documentation you used to deploy your website and worked

Comment: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running

Comment: Nope i took a look at it but it wasn't relevant. I used to get the same HTTP errors when running the site locally but the site used to render and work properly. I'm getting the same error in  heroku but site is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In my case I renamed the "procfile" to "Procfile" updated the contents of the procfile to

```
web: gunicorn website.wsgi:application --log-file -
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
manage.py migrate
```

and this worked

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because Gunicorn is not running.

Try running this command on your local computer: "gunicorn website.wsgi --log-file -
" does it run?

Are there any build errors from Heroku?

Comment: I tried to run the code but since i'm on windows i'm getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
and no there aren't any build errors the only errors i get are mentioned above and the same error keeps on repeating

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and the problem was simple: I forgot to put `gunicorn` to `requirements.txt`, so the heroku server did not install the needed package. I added `gunicorn` to `requirements.txt`, pushed again, and it worked for me!