# Can anyone help me identify that heroku application error

Tags: python, django, heroku

After opening app I deployed, there is an error:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
> heroku logs --tail

Can you please help me solving or identifying that error?

There are logs

```
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.47.6 to 7.53.1.
2021-05-17T08:07:01.958623+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:07:01.958623+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:07:02.185037+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:07:02.185037+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:09:13.560585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=5b27d2eb-9b93-4169-b5a1-c5041f0c46d4 fwd="37.249.138.76" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T08:09:13.788320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=0f06c72b-8d59-4409-9946-a343a7ac7b57 fwd="37.249.138.76" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T08:10:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:10:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9afe7277-a8cc-4782-b52d-bb5698d2273c/activity/builds/be2f281b-2961-4df6-8abd-bd691199f6d4
2021-05-17T08:14:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:14:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9afe7277-a8cc-4782-b52d-bb5698d2273c/activity/builds/aba64d28-3b09-4ca9-a0db-a5277ff0eac5
2021-05-17T08:18:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:18:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9afe7277-a8cc-4782-b52d-bb5698d2273c/activity/builds/9273f61b-0a02-414f-b7cc-0674b19f8b80
2021-05-17T08:27:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:27:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9afe7277-a8cc-4782-b52d-bb5698d2273c/activity/builds/fafc1f20-de69-42db-ac3c-9ff694e26b1c
2021-05-17T08:36:02.612360+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:36:02.612360+00:00 app[api]: Set DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:36:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:36:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9afe7277-a8cc-4782-b52d-bb5698d2273c/activity/builds/1aec1594-6d19-47f8-a451-0c5d1f15c6a3
2021-05-17T08:39:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T08:39:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9afe7277-a8cc-4782-b52d-bb5698d2273c/activity/builds/5171d008-78eb-4fae-a116-b768ff1d159b
2021-05-17T09:32:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T09:32:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9afe7277-a8cc-4782-b52d-bb5698d2273c/activity/builds/0d585658-1af6-42c1-9c0d-e06bc8873f50
2021-05-17T10:26:40.628560+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:26:40.628560+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:27:26.390340+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:27:27.160556+00:00 heroku[run.3098]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-17T10:27:27.539912+00:00 heroku[run.3098]: Awaiting client
2021-05-17T10:27:27.828949+00:00 heroku[run.3098]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2021-05-17T10:27:33.036554+00:00 heroku[run.3098]: Process exited with status 2
2021-05-17T10:27:33.114314+00:00 heroku[run.3098]: State changed from up to complete
2021-05-17T10:27:55.354359+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:27:56.074230+00:00 heroku[run.8859]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-17T10:27:57.101824+00:00 heroku[run.8859]: Awaiting client
2021-05-17T10:27:57.421822+00:00 heroku[run.8859]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2021-05-17T10:28:02.939403+00:00 heroku[run.8859]: Process exited with status 2
2021-05-17T10:28:03.031256+00:00 heroku[run.8859]: State changed from up to complete
2021-05-17T10:41:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:42:35.566369+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-rectangular-00610) by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:42:35.566369+00:00 app[api]: Running release v5 commands by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:42:35.579961+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:42:35.579961+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-rectangular-00610 completed provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:42:36.125632+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f58bcf3c by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:42:36.125632+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:42:44.021375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=26eedc45-1106-4700-87fe-f030f7e8dbd5 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:42:44.261606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=5aef3467-ace1-4b23-97c1-55cbecfbf38a fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:42:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-17T10:42:52.926191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=5af96fed-fc1d-4cca-ad16-b3c0c415ff02 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:42:53.130439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=0f4f9b5b-bedc-4980-a6bd-4d5e72c613aa fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:43:09.084488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=e401b7a2-d108-4464-bbda-d53a7678f2a2 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:43:09.230756+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=05b7e114-46bb-4fb1-a470-715e5e9499aa fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:43:25.092267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=1c770cd6-0768-406b-920e-a1e7a524fd7b fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:43:25.311492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=8b0ef7b1-7631-4d7e-975c-022f2f03ef9e fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:48:12.890530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=1c7c6244-3d61-452f-9e74-51009db2dead fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:48:13.048375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=c9c1bc6b-9633-421b-8d3b-47edc558f518 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:49:15.039546+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=d859b842-a572-4fd5-afcf-cd3538688e5d fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:49:15.203787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=f53fc105-4344-48c4-8905-d94fde7750f5 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:56:13.290200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=f8e7e055-c897-4f0d-b335-65f2a001ea15 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:56:13.520588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=0d57aaa8-35f3-4456-a5b3-73fafc9fa62e fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T10:59:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:59:48.872631+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ac36d40f by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T10:59:48.872631+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user filip.antoniak99@gmail.com
2021-05-17T11:00:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-17T11:00:06.427708+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=c3f11b8f-8ba6-4b53-bef1-30575964b048 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T11:00:06.627461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=642b6026-4a94-4900-94ec-2c47385dfcb9 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T11:00:15.576396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=a6276757-6752-4788-83e2-8d3deb0bcc06 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-17T11:00:15.781029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ergonomizer.herokuapp.com request_id=0b588976-087f-4a95-9416-fbf10edc9165 fwd="31.0.57.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen because heroku may not be able to start your server. Here are few points to notice:

1. The `Procfile` should be at the root of the project.
2. Make sure that you are pointing to the correct path of the `wsgi.py` file.

Here is one of my projects I uploaded on github, have a look through the `Procfile`.

[github-Ajinkya2000](https://github.com/Ajinkya2000/progressor-app)

Comment: hi can you please help me in identifyingthe error with my application when trying to deploy on heroku