# Heroku error at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"

Tags: java, spring, heroku, pom.xml

I'm trying to use Heroku to deploy my spring project, using deploy from Github.

I'm new at Spring and at Heroku.

At first it gives me success, but when i try to access returns me this message

> at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

My pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/3.6.2 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-3.6.2.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.edu.utfpr.sgcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>SGCC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>SGCC</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I don't have a procfile, but I don't know if it's necessary

When i run heroku ps:scale web=1
I receive an status 127, but returns to the same error

> 2021-08-06T00:36:36.163994+00:00 heroku[run.6184]: State changed from starting to up
> 2021-08-06T00:36:36.419540+00:00 heroku[run.6184]: Awaiting client
> 2021-08-06T00:36:36.463704+00:00 heroku[run.6184]: Starting process with command `heroku ps:scale web=1`
> 2021-08-06T00:36:38.857286+00:00 heroku[run.6184]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
> 2021-08-06T00:36:39.385263+00:00 heroku[run.6184]: Process exited with status 127
> 2021-08-06T00:36:39.479070+00:00 heroku[run.6184]: State changed from up to complete

Answer (score 2):

Error H14 with "No web processes running" basically means that you're not running any web dynos. You can use `heroku ps:scale web=1` to start one.

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running) for more details.

Comment: I tried that and still the same error, I edited the post with what I got

Answer (score 1):

- I added below code,

```
gunicorn appn.wsgi
```

OR

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 
web: gunicorn appn.wsgi --log-file -
```

in `Procfile` still face an issue:

```
2022-01-19T15:35:19.020279+00:00 heroku[router]: 
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET 
path="/" host=****.herokuapp.com request_id=eer2323423er32 fwd="125.16.01.197" 
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

- I spend a night to fix this,
- But at the end, I deploy same code on another app & this time it work fine :]