# Multiple packages Python, Heroku not picking up Procfile file

Tags: python, flask, heroku, python-packaging

I am working on a python Flask project with multiple packages. The folder structure is as follows:

```
root
|--programs
   |--package_1
      |--__init__.py
      |--app.py
   |--package_2
      |--__init__.py
      |--pythonfiles2.py
   |--package_2
      |--__init__.py
      |--pythonfiles3.py
   |--main.py
   |--.env
|--docs
|--requirements.txt
|--runtime.txt
|--Procfile
```

I am hosting the project on Heroku, and the main.py file is as follows:

```
from package_1.app import flask_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
   flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

As can be seen above, I initialise `flask_app` in one of the packages and then import it into the main file. Further, the Procfile for the project is situated in the `programs` directory.

However, when I deploy the application I get this error:
`No web processes running`

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Thank you!

Edit: the Procfile contains: `web gunicorn programs.main:flask_app`

Comment: `Procfile` must be in the root dir not in a subfolder.

Comment: @basicmojo I have tried both within the ```programs``` folder and outside of. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was because of the location of the `.env` file. I needed, counter-intuitively, to store the `.env` file outside the `programs` directory.

That is, the new folder structure is:

```
root
|--programs
   |--package_1
      |--__init__.py
      |--app.py
   |--package_2
      |--__init__.py
      |--pythonfiles2.py
   |--package_2
      |--__init__.py
      |--pythonfiles3.py
   |--main.py
|--docs
|--requirements.txt
|--runtime.txt
|--Procfile
|--.env
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$ heroku ps:scale web=1` ?

If that didn't work can you please share your Procfile ?

Comment: I have tried that, with regards to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running ... still no luck! Also, just shared Procfile

Comment: Are the colon and space in Procfile in the right place? Even those can create problems. Maybe try to paste this in your Procfile instead `web: gunicorn main:app`  and place your `main.py` file in the same directory as Procfile and `requirements.txt`.