# Method Not Allowed error after deploying python app on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, beautifulsoup

I have scrapped a website and after scrapping i have successfully deployed it on heroku.
But it gives me the error.
"Method Not Allowed"
I cannot understand the error please help me to solve this error.
This is link my python app deployed on heroku.
https://git.heroku.com/toscrape-scrape.git

Answer (score 1):

You can find your app over here https://toscrape-scrape.herokuapp.com/ instead of https://git.heroku.com/toscrape-scrape.git

You seem to have other errors, check your logs.

Comment: I have also check this but it gives me the Application error

Comment: @NomanEjaz You got "Method Not Allowed" because you accessed the wrong link.
You getting an Application Error because there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: How can i solve this error.

Comment: @NomanEjaz There is no way I on someone can help you without seeing your code or knowing what you exactly did.
Like I said, you need to check your logs.

Comment: I have check my logs by heroku logs --tail but gives me h14 error.

Comment: And h14 error means no web dynos running but how can i ran these error

Comment: Please go through the following link. It might help you . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running