# A Hello World in django isn't working when deplyed to heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I started learning django today and made a hello world thing, and want to deploy it to heroku, the build suceeded but when I enter the app it gives me the error

"Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail"

I checked the logs and this is what it said

```
2022-01-08T10:11:47.583930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=justatest11lmao.herokuapp.com 
request_id=f1d12c52-396c-4550-b657-488b3c1734cf fwd="122.52.35.99" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-08T10:11:48.791011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=justatest11lmao.herokuapp.com 
request_id=c6c80d4c-7b46-4614-a606-9c71eb922dac fwd="122.52.35.99" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-08T10:17:08.913462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=justatest11lmao.herokuapp.com 
request_id=cbe21638-ec17-445e-a037-c2c9d0e09bcb fwd="122.52.35.99" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-08T10:17:09.961200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=justatest11lmao.herokuapp.com 
request_id=fbe70f09-91f1-4815-9b5b-06475476e3de fwd="122.52.35.99" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-08T10:21:40.857058+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=justatest11lmao.herokuapp.com 
request_id=c631842b-7696-488e-a28c-4efa9782c1b9 fwd="122.52.35.99" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-08T10:21:41.924967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=justatest11lmao.herokuapp.com 
request_id=3a70e80d-e807-41c3-9bd4-d5f809b3672e fwd="122.52.35.99" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I'm new so I would really appreciate it if it is explained in a beginner-friendly manner, thank you!

Comment: Is there any Traceback in your logs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [H14 error in heroku - "no web processes running"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running)