# Django Heroku Application Erorr

Tags: python, django, heroku, favicon

I made a small site and I wanted to publish it on heroku. However, some errors arose during this time.

The site gave a favicon.ico error, so I wondered if there was a problem with the django project I coded, so I opened a new clean project and the same problem arose.

settings.py

```
    """

Django settings for yayinda project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/

"""

import os

from pathlib import Path

import django_heroku

django_heroku.settings(locals())

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production

# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-6hv!w%64=3)hj7hix=tzv^$9n4-mn0l@!=4$uax%gs)mtsr)z0'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1','yayinda.herokuapp.com']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',

    'django.contrib.auth',

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    'django.contrib.sessions',

    'django.contrib.messages',

    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'yayinda_deneme'

]

MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'yayinda.urls'

TEMPLATES = [

    {

        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',

        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],

        'APP_DIRS': True,

        'OPTIONS': {

            'context_processors': [

                'django.template.context_processors.debug',

                'django.template.context_processors.request',

                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],

        },

    },

]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'yayinda.wsgi.application'

# Database

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',

        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',

    }

}

# Password validation

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [

    {

        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',

    },

    {

        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',

    },

    {

        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',

    },

    {

        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',

    },

]

# Internationalization

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Default primary key field type

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

procfile

```
web: gunicorn yayinda.wsgi --log-file -
```

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.0

certifi==2021.10.8

charset-normalizer==2.0.12

dj-database-url==0.5.0

Django==4.0.3

django-downloadview==2.3.0

django-heroku==0.3.1

gunicorn==20.1.0

idna==3.3

Pillow==9.0.1

psycopg2==2.9.3

requests==2.27.1

sqlparse==0.4.2

tzdata==2021.5

urllib3==1.26.8

whitenoise==6.0.0
```

This is what I get when I type the code on the opened page into the terminal.

```
PS D:\djangodeneme\yayinda> heroku logs --tail
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.4.
2022-03-12T13:46:06.983224+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:46:06.983224+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:46:07.140957+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:46:07.140957+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:47:01.416578+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=f559e6ce-ee36-4c22-8d19-12cd1ccf82c8 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T13:47:01.633087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=ee3eba7d-f193-47e3-b910-fa08b36c69a0 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T13:48:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:48:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/0388f3d6-f9c4-4847-9312-c69c934b1765/activity/builds/d5e50ce4-b28b-4e24-a271-91baa38befca
2022-03-12T13:49:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:50:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/0388f3d6-f9c4-4847-9312-c69c934b1765/activity/builds/f41db8c6-d63b-4afd-ba9c-a9185648df66
2022-03-12T13:53:51.248040+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:53:51.248040+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:53:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:54:47.310932+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-rugged-19321) by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:54:47.310932+00:00 app[api]: Running release v4 commands by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:54:47.325595+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:54:47.325595+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-rugged-19321 completed provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:54:47.881242+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 379e9544 by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:54:47.881242+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T13:54:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-03-12T13:55:03.578742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=addf971e-b6b2-4cf5-9003-41c7972fb5cb fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T13:55:03.974942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=b044954c-b1e0-4bcc-a911-ccc3957fd6bc fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:01:31.317177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=e70d2c6b-e416-4595-987f-93e44db6c2f1 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:01:31.561705+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=f7505281-7af9-4ba5-b3a0-d4aa24bdfe56 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:02:01.609523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=5753474d-a55e-48f2-81ad-fb31e9ee61d8 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:02:02.826967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=59a36507-0cb7-46f5-a9ba-81301c322a1f fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:03:49.002682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=285cc209-b62b-40fb-87df-4ded42b9bdc0 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:03:49.218024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=7603e5b3-5c93-4ac8-a1fe-4585cadc0021 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:03:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:04:26.247384+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 09a5d779 by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:04:26.247384+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:04:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-03-12T14:04:42.437350+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=77cc1846-6299-4d1e-ae21-c7763f759718 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:04:42.661966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=bf6fd5a5-8c88-4f58-a4a3-7e0b83d2d719 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:07:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:07:50.418401+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 51051dcd by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:07:50.418401+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:07:55.847024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=fbd4efe8-d9ff-44c2-b951-46e956a57d3e fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:07:56.091230+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=e96a3bfb-2f81-4108-adac-5bab5c20f482 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:08:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-03-12T14:08:04.033532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=ef9c17f8-fe9c-4512-85e5-d44546ede1d6 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:08:04.251342+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=742721f7-dfe6-4031-b1f1-2fcdcb29a6ea fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:08:07.825536+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=9fb741ef-077e-411a-9490-b96874c8c8c0 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:08:08.047860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=c125324c-4d7b-49e2-a572-fc1f5e078b54 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:08:38.207584+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=4c904773-88c5-4ff8-b915-724e9c7feea5 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:08:38.447310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=79e112f2-6aa3-4510-800b-55c1d6c3e459 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:11:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:11:59.580860+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7683176f by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:11:59.580860+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:12:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-03-12T14:12:13.445849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=2819f83b-ca9d-4585-95bf-afd45bcc6bef fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:12:13.660117+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=aa5e5730-6ad7-4c82-8167-526c2a48d1d9 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:13:34.825837+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic` by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:13:39.560373+00:00 heroku[run.8341]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-12T14:13:39.661876+00:00 heroku[run.8341]: Awaiting client
2022-03-12T14:13:39.677030+00:00 heroku[run.8341]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic`
2022-03-12T14:13:43.813426+00:00 heroku[run.8341]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-12T14:13:43.888075+00:00 heroku[run.8341]: State changed from up to complete
2022-03-12T14:15:14.380784+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic` by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:15:19.688095+00:00 heroku[run.4059]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-12T14:15:19.833355+00:00 heroku[run.4059]: Awaiting client
2022-03-12T14:15:19.849054+00:00 heroku[run.4059]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic`
2022-03-12T14:15:24.347987+00:00 heroku[run.4059]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-12T14:15:24.406741+00:00 heroku[run.4059]: State changed from up to complete
2022-03-12T14:15:52.557392+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic` by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:15:56.911751+00:00 heroku[run.7187]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-12T14:15:56.947023+00:00 heroku[run.7187]: Awaiting client
2022-03-12T14:15:56.964428+00:00 heroku[run.7187]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic`
2022-03-12T14:16:01.094969+00:00 heroku[run.7187]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-12T14:16:01.226583+00:00 heroku[run.7187]: State changed from up to complete
2022-03-12T14:16:28.893372+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:16:28.893372+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:16:34.534396+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic` by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:16:38.841287+00:00 heroku[run.5702]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-12T14:16:38.843466+00:00 heroku[run.5702]: Awaiting client
2022-03-12T14:16:38.862208+00:00 heroku[run.5702]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic`
2022-03-12T14:16:43.180147+00:00 heroku[run.5702]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-12T14:16:43.364940+00:00 heroku[run.5702]: State changed from up to complete
2022-03-12T14:16:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:17:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/0388f3d6-f9c4-4847-9312-c69c934b1765/activity/builds/d05c90b1-d5f8-4400-9596-303a4c638cca
2022-03-12T14:25:12.228185+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:25:12.228185+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:25:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:25:55.745613+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:25:55.745613+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 4cdf53cd by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:26:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-03-12T14:26:11.950021+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=6d69582f-67d6-4f6a-aec3-b7a5146cf740 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:26:12.134955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=02794f2b-99e9-4920-805a-0461f7ae2dae fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:33:17.897731+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=16b28df9-3b08-48b7-9630-57bfc2043b5b fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:33:18.087174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=79f18140-173e-477e-b4ea-056e4146c151 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:33:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:33:48.708150+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:33:48.708150+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 4119d15f by user halilibohosnar@gmail.com
2022-03-12T14:33:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-03-12T14:34:04.695719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=3447aac6-3f2b-487c-944b-a3c7d9c8eb01 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T14:34:04.869102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yayinda.herokuapp.com request_id=b3476fdb-c53b-4ed2-ad4d-28a6cc281313 fwd="78.163.104.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

the error i get is ss
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXIDy.png)

Comment: Have you tried running `heroku ps:scale web=1` to check if the app is active?

Comment: Make sure you name your Procfile `Procfile` and not `Procfile.txt` or `procfile`, and that it is in the root of your project (where your settings.py file is).  Also check out the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running).