# Java Spring Boot Deployment with GitHub

Tags: github, heroku, deployment

If I build and deploy the code linked below through CLI it works successfully. It also builds and runs locally. I am trying to set it up to deploy through github, but when I do that I get an 'application error' when trying to access the page via the url. Looking at the logs, I don't think there are any errors from the build, but I do get the following message when I try to access the url:

at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=bug-tracker-url.herokuapp.com request_id=620ec127-49ea-4aea-8f0c-d1b228e6cb03 fwd="86.180.101.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

This is the repo I'm trying to use to deploy:
https://github.com/jamesgiddings/bugtracker

I have tried running heroku ps:scale web=1 -a

This returns Couldn't find that process type

I did also try adding both jvm and java to the build packs. This allows me to run heroku ps:scale web=1 -a successfully, but then when I try to access the website I get

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET

Comment: Have you tried [spinning up a web dyno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41811595/354577)?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. I got the following error: Couldn't find that process type

Comment: I now have the ps:scale web=1 command scaling dynos to 1:free, but the website error is unchanged.

Comment: "but the website error is unchanged"—surely the _log_ says something different now? If you are running a web dyno, the logs should no longer be saying "No web processes running". Please [edit] the updated error messages into your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that. With the change to allow the ps:scale, I now get error code h10.

Comment: Okay, well, on its own that doesn't tell us anything useful. What do the logs say above that? There should be additional output.

Comment: So I had a look, and there was an error relating to deploying in development mode. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running project in development mode with no access to folder '/tmp/build_bce7b98c'. When I built through the cli I did use -Pproduction, but I don't know how to achieve the same through a github deployment.