# Can't Deploy FastAPI to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, fastapi

I changed my Procfile to several things. I quadrupled check to make sure I had everything installed. I triple checked all my paths and naming. Nothing has worked. The top portion is my "main.py" and the bottom is heroku log.

Error:

```
web: uvicorn main:app --workers 4 (failed)**, **web gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:server(Failed)
```

Code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from videoGames import vgRouter

# Defining our Server
server = FastAPI()

origins = ['*']

server.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware, 
    allow_origins = origins,
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods = ['*'],
    allow_headers = ['*'],
)

@server.get('/')
def welcomeUser():
    return {"message": "Welcome to my API!"}
    
    # Using our Video Games router
    server.include_router(vgRouter.router)

2022-10-05T03:08:40.691697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=land-of-gamingapi.herokuapp.com request_id=b6f472d3-a557-4bbd-9419-53d1542139be 
fwd="23.84.247.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-05T03:08:40.830495+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=land-of-gamingapi.herokuapp.com request_id=902be7d5-9ee5-400e-bb25-1958b11abdc4 
fwd="23.84.247.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-05T03:08:41.413337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=land-of-gamingapi.herokuapp.com request_id=c94caef3-e237-4da0-93e8-42f4330dfde1 
fwd="23.84.247.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-05T03:08:41.641962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=land-of-gamingapi.herokuapp.com request_id=95be4fd7-bc74-4541-bb54-4f737b02be19 fwd="23.84.247.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: "No web processes running" usually just means your web dynos are scaled to zero. [Try scaling them up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41811595/354577).