# Heroku app error, previously working fine

Tags: heroku

We have an app that was working fine in Heroku, now stopped working, suddenly.
As per logs, it is throwing these lines:

```
2022-12-04T15:54:00.247653+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OJTs1y-" host=mentee-h4i.herokuapp.com request_id=5c69dcdd-083a-4b78-a125-cdd39778e5c9 fwd="181.165.121.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-04T15:54:05.806894+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OJTs3NA" host=mentee-h4i.herokuapp.com request_id=9bf65614-31e0-49e4-a2e6-affb15592aec fwd="181.165.121.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running).
But I think the reason for the problem is that Heroku shut down the free tier on November 28, 2022.

Answer (score 0):

@Hukys is correct. Heroku no longer provides free dyno plans.

Although if you have previously deployed apps, you can still access them after subscribing to one of their plans. If you are still experiencing an **H14 error**, try to **reconfigure your dyno**. Just change your dyno type to the subscribed plan and make sure you have toggle the selected dyno to the right in order to enable it.

[image]